# Writing uin32_t to asio::streambuf

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, iostream

I'm trying to set up writing `uint32_t`s into a buffer that I'm going to send across the wire but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. Initially I assumed that `operator<<` would handle it correctly and write the 4 bytes to the buffer (assuming I had used `htonl` before). Instead I started getting values that didn't make any sense. I noticed it when sometimes writing a single int to the stream sometimes increased the size of buffer by up to ten bytes instead of the expected four. I wrote up a short test and realized that it's actually dumping the integers in ascii to the buffer. I think I've figured out a way around it but it feels *hacky*, so I'm looking for a better way, or justification on why what I'm doing is actually right.

Here'ssome example code:

```
  boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
  std::ostream os(&buffer);

  uint32_t value = 0x12345678;
  os << value; // Gives ascii 305419896

  os.write((const char *) &value, sizeof(value)); // fives 0x12345678
```

Is there a better way to do this than my last line of code?

Comment: Remember too that the int will be packed in using the local machine's native endian (little/big)... it might be best to ensure network endian using `htonl` and `ntohl` or similar to ensure compatibility into the future. Also the `write` method is AFAIK the best way to perform this anyway. If you have more fields it might be best making a packed struct and writing the whole struct to the stream in one go.

Comment: I did say that I was using htonl. For this in particular I can't use a packed struct, but it's a good idea I know I'll use shortly in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Another thing you may want to consider is run length encoding to save bandwidth, depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into using that if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine, but it *is* possible to write to streambuf directly:

```
buffer.commit(boost::asio::buffer_copy(
    buffer.prepare(sizeof(value)),
    boost::asio::buffer(&value, sizeof(value))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual way of doing it. You can save some time and code if you add a little code between.

```
template<class T> void append(T value)
{
    static_assert(std::is_fundamental<T>::value, __FUNCTION__);
    //Convert here to correct endian
    append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}

template<class T> void append(const T *app, std::size_t size)
{
    return append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(app), size);
}

void append(const char *s, std::size_t length)
{
    //append to buffer
}
```

Remember to convert to correct endian when you receive the data. Or send it directly in the correct format if you know what the remote-machine expects.

Also you *could* check for endianness like this:

```
static bool IsBigEndian(void)
{
    union
    {
        uint32_t i;
        char c[4];
    } endi = { 0x01020304 };
    return endi.c[0] == 1;
}
```

Comment: It's redundant to check endianness at run-time, since you already know it at compile-time.

Comment: I'm aware of this. This is a suggestion, as you can read from the answer.